# Can backlinks to my site increase my chances of plugin rejection

Tags: plugins

I am creating a custom plugin. I want to add a custom support functionality in it. This will definately create backlinks for my website.

Can adding this functionality be the reason that my plugin can be rejected from wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not creating plugin which will put link back to your site automatically without user consent I do not see a reason why that will be problem. WordPress community can reject your plugin if it is spam or have issues with security..